# Oracle SQL how to call created function

Tags: sql, function

I made a function in Oracle that calculates the distance between two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` ,here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION afstand_cart (x1 IN number, x2 IN number, y1 IN number, y2 IN number)
RETURN number IS
BEGIN
return sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
END;
```

Now how do I call this function?

```
SELECT afstand_cart(0,0,1,1) FROM dual
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: this is PLSQL right?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in Oracle is to use call :

```
CALL afstand_cart(0,0,1,1)
```

[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4008.htm)